# Logic behind v.size()-1?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and the book said the last element in the vector is v[v.size()-1]. What is the logic behind this? Hows size-1 giving me the last element? Would it not give me second from the last element?

Thanks

Comment: you need to read about array indexing

Comment: Ask youself, what is the first index of a vector?  If a vector has a size of one, and you subtract one from it, what value do it you get?

Comment: Arrays, vectors, etc. (almost) always start at position 0 instead of 1. NathanOliver's comment describes it well.

Comment: Take care that the `vector` is not empty before using that approach. Also note that in modern C++ this is formalized in [the `std::vector::back` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the book said the last element in the vector is `v[v.size()-1]`

That's true, but only when `v.size() > 0`. If the vector is empty, its size is 0, but the value returned by [`std::vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is of type `std::vector::size_type` which is an *unsigned* integer type (usually `std::size_t`), so that the result "wraps around" becoming an "unexpected" huge value (the maximum representable value of `size_type`, actually).

You can also use `v.back()`, where [`std::vector::back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) "returns reference to the last element in the container. Calling `back` on an empty container causes [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)."

> What is the logic behind this?

In C++, vector (and array) indeces start from 0, so that `v[0]` would return a reference to the *first* element, if present. In general accessing a nonexistent element through `operator[]` is undefined behavior.

To picture it, let's consider a vector of size 5.

```
  v[0]  v[1]  v[2]  v[3]  v[4]
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+ - -
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+ - - 
   ^                             ^
v.begin()                     v.end()
```

Note that the `v.end()` iterator points exactly at `v.begin() + v.size()` and that the last accessible element is the one before that.

Comment: aahhh this picture is really helpful. vector size is 5 but since vector start at 0 size-1 is gives me the last element v[4]. Thanks. I guess i got confused with the numbers of size and the numbers of vector.

Answer (score 2):

If there's one element, it's element zero. If there are two elements, they are zero and one. So the last element is the element with an index one less than the number of elements.

It may help intuitively to think as an element's index as its distance from the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Do you undestand memory position? All vectors are index starting at 0, not at one. So if your vectors has 10 elements, the last is at the position 9.

This occurs because C language has arrays. Arrays are pointers to a position memory, so the position 0 means the start of the array, if you get the position 1 you add a value to the pointer.

If you have `int[] arr = ...`

- `arr[0]` has the same value of `arr`
- `arr[1]` can be replaced by `arr + sizeof(int)`

Comment: If `arr + sizeof(int)` is intended to be code, it's wrong because of `arr`'s type.

Comment: *Arrays are pointers to a position memory* They are most certainly not pointers.  Arrays are arrays, pointers are pointers.  An array name can *decay* into a pointer, but there are not the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver, well both are true actually. At runtime, an array (well c-style arrays to be exact) is only stored as the address of it's first element, so it is a pointer. At compile-time, however they are arrays.

Comment: @Phantomas That's not a particularly good way of looking at it because the same can be said for any object. At runtime everything is either a direct address or an offset from an address. Or maybe not. C++ could be implemented atop a system based on unicorns and fairy dust that does something utterly bizarre and magical in the back end. Best to think in terms of the abstraction presented by C++ where an array is an array and a pointer is a pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the question is about the logic behind. If you ever had developed a program using Assembly Language, you will understand that everything is a pointer. An array is a pointer to a start position, then you add offsets to the start position. This is the logic behind, all languages work in that way because the computer work as it.